# Caption settings before and after loading caption package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, margins

Why do captions look so different after the mere loading of the caption package? What are the default settings for a caption BEFORE loading the caption package? I would prefer to be able to load most of those preferences but still be able to make small adjustments with caption.

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, notitlepage]{revtex4-1} %, prX
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,belowskip=4pt,aboveskip=4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{llamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam
facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio
placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor.mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus,
ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus
congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor.
Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus sagittis
dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna.
Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

Versus the same example when uncommenting the `caption` package

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: The taste of `caption`'s author is different from `revtex4-1`'s author; they define different defaults.  You cannot take over `revtex`'s defaults; you have to mimic it with `caption`.

Comment: Is there a way of importing this in \captionsetup or similarly?

Comment: I'm afraid not; there is no such thing like inheritance here.

Comment: The `caption` package is mostly incompatible with `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Is there a command for making the text push to the end of the line before starting a new one? This is the most disturbing consequence for me.

Comment: This is not a problem of different taste, I (as the author of the caption package) do not have an own taste regarding captions, but the caption package tries to import the settings of the document class instead. However, there is no standardized way of defining (or importing) caption parameters, so to archive this goal extra code needs to be written for every single document class. And there is no such extra code for detecting the revtex document class and importing the settings from the revtex class inside the caption package yet.